# The geodesic equation of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial{s}}L(g_{t}, \lambda_{s})\big[ \frac{\partial}{\partial{s}} \gamma_{s}\big]$

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I was taking a look at the this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0203.pdf) where I encountered the following situation: Let $S$ be a compact surface without boundary components with genus $\geq 2$ and let $g_{t}$ be a family of Riemannian metrics on the surface and let $\gamma_{t}$ be a family of closed geodesics with respect to $g_{t}$ on $S$. Then if we let $L(g_{t}, \gamma_{s})$ be the arc length of $\gamma_{s}$ with respect with the metric $g_{t}$ then we have that the geodesic equation takes the form (equation 2.1 in the paper):

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{s}}L(g_{t}, \lambda_{s})\big[ \frac{\partial}{\partial{s}} \gamma_{s}\big] \bigg\vert_{s=s_0}=0$$
> when $\gamma_{s_{0}}$ is a $g_{t}$ geodesic.

I don't have much background in Riemannanian geometry but I wanted to understand what the author means by "geodesic equation". I understand this intuitively as the length functional $L(g_{t}, \cdot)$ as being a function of curves that has critical points at geodesics.

I would much appreciate precise definitions or referrals to references.

Comment: I don’t see an equation yet. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, the highlighted derivative should be equal to zero.